# swift forcing objective-c int to be assigned as Int32 then crashing

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, int

I have an objective c property that has been declared as

```
@property int xmBufferSize;
```

If I do `sharedExample.xmBufferSize = 1024` it just works fine
but when I am trying to set an integer value for that property from another variable

```
var getThat:Int = dict["bufferSize"]!.integerValue
sharedExample.xmBufferSize = getThat
```

It can't do above

`Cannot assign a value of type 'Int' to a value of type 'Int32'`

If I force this to

```
sharedExample.xmBufferSize =dict["bufferSize"] as! Int32
```

It is crashing with Error

**`Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber'  to 'Swift.Int32`'**

EDIT::::
Dict init, there are other objects in dict besides integers

```
var bufferSize:Int = 1024
var dict = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>() = ["bufferSize":bufferSize]
```

Comment: `getThat` is `Int`. Either change `getThat` to `Int32` and replace `.integerValue` with `.intValue` or `sharedExample.xmlBufferSize = Int32(getThat)`.

Comment: As above a part of the problem is different sized of the integer. It is best to explicitly set these, `uint32_t` in Objective-C and `Int32` in Swift. Then you know exactly what the sizes are. Swift does not handle size casts implicitly so you have to know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value in `dict` is an `NSNumber`, which cannot be cast or directly converted to `Int32`. You can first obtain the `NSNumber` and then call `intValue` on it:

```
if let bufferSize = dict["bufferSize"] as? NSNumber {
    sharedExample.xmlBufferSize = bufferSize.intValue
}
```

The `if let … as?` allows you to verify that the value is indeed an `NSNumber`, since (as you said) there can be other types of objects in `dict`. The then-branch will only execute if `dict["bufferSize"]` exists and is an `NSNumber`.

(Note: You can also try `integerValue` if `intValue` gives the wrong type, or convert the resulting integer – `CInt(bufferSize.integerValue)` – as needed. Swift doesn't do implicit conversions between different integer types, so you need to match exactly.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your NSNumber to Int32.

```
sharedExample.xmBufferSize = dict["bufferSize"]!.intValue
```

Answer (score -1):

Use type conversion, not as:

```
sharedExample.xmBufferSize = Int32(dict["bufferSize"] as! Int)
```

That should work.

Comment: `Cannot find an initializer for type 'Int32' that accepts an argument list of type '(AnyObject?)'`

Comment: Your answer is incorrect because Int32 doesn't accept AnyObject as a parameter.